# Getting a cross-section from power-spectrum

Tags: matlab, fft

I am currently trying to use spectral-methods to analyse topographic landscapes.

When i FFT the landscape and plot the power-spectrum. From the power-spectrum an orientation of the structures in the landscape can be found.

**2D power-spectrum:-** [image: 2D power-spectrum]

In this power-spectrum, i would like to make a cross-section. 
This is easy when the peak amplitude orientation is along the x or y-axis. 
But for this area (and others), this is not the case.

**Cross-section from another area - orientated along the y-axis:-** [image: Cross-section from another area - orientated along the y-axis]

My problem is i want to make a cross-section along the peaks in 1, and i just cant seem to figure it out how.

If anyone could point me towards some solution for this. Been stuck here for a couple of days now.

**Edit 1**
 *I would like the cross-section, to be a line along the peak orientation.*

**Edit 2**
*Improved the first image to show where i want my cross-section*

Comment: take the max of each row of your iFFT plot ? your question is a little vague, do you want your cross section to be a line or simply the max value of each row / column?

Comment: Yeah i know its a little vague :/ 

I would it to be a line, so i can see the peaks along this line. I have tried it with the max values, didn't really give me a plot with new information.

Comment: hmmm. Do you want to perhaps draw on your image the line you are looking for?

Comment: I have updated image 1 to show where i would like to do my cross-section

Comment: you could potentially do a windowed average, pick a few points that are highest and then linear interpolate it and force it to go through the origin using a forced interpolation. This should give you the line, then you need to use something like https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/1853-linepoints to get the coordinates of the iFFT matrix you are interested in.

Comment: also, you might want to consider https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ginput.html using your hand input to mark the line you want, since it looks like you might want multiple lines, just set to extract 2 points and use the linepoints function to generate coordinates and then use it for your cross-section.

Comment: Thanks, ill look in to this. 
Looks like it could be a solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was, as GameOfThrows suggested:

- Pick 2 (or more) points on the orientation i want
- used Least squares on the points to create the line
- Setup a meshgrid for the interpolation.
- Use the interp2 function on the new line.
- define a proper axis for the section

In my final cross section i ended up having multiple lines in it, that way i was sure to hit the max amplitudes.

i was a little with the answer to my question, but i have been busy :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ginput built-in matlab function to store 2 (x,y) coordinates of your power spectrum and then use this values to delimit a profile to be interpolated.