# How to plot 2D Power Spectrum

Tags: matlab, fft

Most academic papers and research ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38310444/getting-a-cross-section-from-power-spectrum), [here](https://ars.els-cdn.com/content/image/1-s2.0-S0022460X16302851-gr13.jpg), and [the one that I'm trying to reproduce](https://mega.nz/#!vp9WFDbb!pEG8pem9n2SaX8IHxbUxnD4JT6ngp0nF608T3zAeiJY)(Fig. 3 Page 3) ) represent the spectrum graph in Magnitude/Phase versus Frequency/Wavenumber. I got confused for 2D images since I don't have the sampling rate as in 1D case.

```
img=imread('cameraman.tif');
F=fftshift(fft2(img));
F_mag=abs(F);
```

Now to plot the spectrum, what is my frequency vector? How do I generate the vectors for 2D image? For an image that have size:

```
[M,N]=size(img);
fx = [fs/2*linspace(0,1,N/2+1)];
fy = [fs/2*linspace(0,1,M/2+1)];
```

Is that correct? But what is my sampling rate `fs`? If you do have a moment to have look at PDF file I attached (I really hope you do), the figure 3 axes (both `k_1` and `k_2`) ranges from `-200` to `200` in both `x` and `y` axis, how did the author get that specific range?

Comment: If you don't have units, the answer I posted in the duplicate question is valid for any number of dimensions. If you do have units (e.g. meters) then you can compute the frequency as (1/m) in the same way that for time signals the units are seconds and the frequencies are measured in Hz (1/s). Your second link uses 1/m. Your third link (figure 2) seems to simply use the integer *k* values (i.e. the index into the result of the FFT, with 0 moved to the middle as per `fftshift`).

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thank you so much for the reply! Just to be sure, if the unit is in meter, that would mean how much pixels it's equivalent to the real world measurement of the object through the lens right? And for the third link, if you meant the Fig. 3 (because Fig. 2 uses spatial `x` and `y`), the `k` indices you meant is generated via `meshgrid` (the coordinates of each of the location of the image)? If so, the operation of Eqn. 14 `(a'k1+b'k2)` would be the multiplication of the constants with the `k` indices? It seems odd to me. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Sorry for a long comment :)

Comment: Indeed, I meant fig. 3, that was a typo. The *k* is the index into the matrix `F_mag` in your code above. Each row is a different integer *k*, same for columns. After using `fftshift` your *k_i* run from `-size(F,i)/2` to `size(F,i)/2-1` for even-sized images.

Comment: That would be the row and column indices that rearranged with zero at center! If you don't mind have a look at my simple code, would my method of operation for this `(a'k1+b'k2)` correct?`[m, n]=size(F);`
`[M,N] = meshgrid(1:m,1:n);`
`K = [M(:), N(:)];` `B=[0.1; 0.2];` `hat=reshape(K*B,m,n);` where `B` is the constant for `a'` and `b'` respectively. Thanks once again!

Comment: Use `ndgrid` instead of `meshgrid` (as it'll produce the correct sizes for `M` and `N`, test with an F that is not square to make sure), and make sure that you include k=0! `[M,N]=ndgrid(0:m-1,0:n-1)`. Then `M-floor(m/2)` and `N-floor(n/2)` are the versions with 0 at the center, if you need that.

Comment: Thanks you @CrisLuengo! Can't say how much I appreciate this! :)